# Redirecting Subscriber Users to the home page after updating their profile

Tags: wp-redirect

So, I found an older solution that doesn't seem to work so I'm asking again.

When users edit their profile, I'd like them to be redirected to the home page. What is the code that will allow me to do that, and where would I place it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this links will help you,

[link](https://thomasgriffin.io/how-to-redirect-users-after-they-update-their-profiles-in-wordpress/)

OR

This is the function that you need:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'custom_profile_redirect', 12 );
function custom_profile_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url() ) );
    exit;
}
```

You can also set it for a specific User Role:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'custom_profile_redirect', 12 );
function custom_profile_redirect() {
  if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
      wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url() ) );
      exit;
  }
}
```